# How to disable inline click-to-edit mode in Jira?

Tags: jira

When using the Jira issue tracker, I'm mostly viewing tickets.

I often want to click on items in the text, or select words. I *rarely* want to edit a ticket.

But when I click in any Jira field, that field is transformed into an "edit mode":

---

Initial state:

> [image: initial state]

If you hover your mouse over the description area, it turns on a hover state:

> [image: hover state]

If you click in the description area, an edit mode is activated:

> [image: click state]

---

This is incredibly annoying, as it breaks all the common ways I select text. It's also easy to accidentally edit a ticket when you really only mean to read it or select text.

How can I prevent this from happening? I want to click on text and to select it, NOT edit that text.

How can I turn off this inline editing mode? Preferably on a per-user basis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the permission of edit Summary and Description of the Jira field. But if you are a non-admin user you will not be able to perform this action. You need to contact to admin of the project.

See documentation of [Modifying field behavior](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/specifying-field-behavior-861253403.html?_ga=2.179775140.1868381501.1592548705-19204599.1589889518#Specifyingfieldbehavior-changingfields) from Administering Jira applications Support page to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the user. Not only does it change mode, it scrolls to the top of the page so you lose your place. Let's have the option to edit by clicking the scroll bar only. And preferably keep the cursor at the same point in both modes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155522)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the user. Not only does it change mode, it scrolls to the top of the page so you lose your place. Let's have the option to edit by clicking the scroll bar only. And preferably keep the cursor at the same point in both modes.

PS: A Google search finds plenty of users with this problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155523)